# Is it possible to get audit events in acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to get data from Acumatica on every Audit Insert. I tried RowPersisted event on Audit History Screen, but it's not working.

What I am trying to accomplish is

When Someone creates a AP or AR it writes down on Audit.
I need to get that data on real-time.

Comment: Can you please expand on what specific AP or AR Document and which "Audit History" page you attempted to modify (EX SE000040)

Comment: When a new AP or AR document is created, are you sending this information to a third party app or use it internally in your customization to execute some other custom logic?

Comment: I'm trying to implement push notifications, my way was to get the event every inserted data on audit history. Push Notifications it was added on Acumatica 2017 R2. Thanks! I'm working on it.

Comment: Why don't just use acumatica push notifications?

Comment: I have not used it, but my understanding after attending the last Acumatica summit is there is (or will be) some of this functionality in the base product. The logic being triggers of events such as new records. If @Kirill mentioned this I would assume the existing push notification feature might also work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I used **Push Notifications** on 2017R2 Acumatica. 
Attached it to a **Webhook** using **NodeJS** and modified data that I needed to constantly **post Events** created by **Push Notifications** to **Slack**. :) Thanks guys.